# What are security advantages of pass in comparison to KeepassXC (GUI App)?

Tags: passwords, password-management

At the moment I use [KeepassXC](https://keepassxc.org/) on macOS. Before I used *KeepassX*, which discontinued their development.

I am considering switching to command line client [pass - the standard unix password manager](https://www.passwordstore.org/), because of simplicity and UNIX like software.

I found a Hackernews [discussion](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7495337) with a major flaw:

> There's one problem here: by storing passwords in a series of flat
>   files, you give away that a password to a given site or location
>   exists. That alone can be data that a user doesn't want to share.

I wish to have my passwords 100% private and no agency and/or malware to read it out.

Are there any benefits of using *pass* over the "easy to use" GUI *KeepassXC*?

Comment: If you're looking at pass but concerned about confidentiality of your list [pwd.sh](https://github.com/drduh/pwd.sh) might be closer to solving your needs.

Comment: "Are there any benefits of using pass over the "easy to use" GUI KeepassXC?" Pass is a command line tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the user's capabilities and requirements, the biggest flaw might certainly be lack of a GUI. Fortunately, there's [QtPass](https://qtpass.org/) (available for Linux/macOS/Windows) to remedy that flaw.

What Hackernews see as a major flaw is none in my eyes (also see the Wikipedia article on [Security Through Obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity)) - no one is forcing you to name your plain text files so that they'd reveal what they're for. And even if you do: good luck breaking them open (given that you've created a good keypair which you're guarding properly).

If you're looking for arguments beyond UI, it's worth mentioning that [GoPass](https://www.gopass.pw/) is compatible with `pass` in that they can be used alongside one another (i.e. having GoPass access the same folder as `pass`, plus any others). GoPass allows you very fine-grained control over who (i.e. which keys) can access what passwords.

Also, KeepassX(C) uses a database, which can, and does (speaking from friends' experiences, unfortunately) break. Since, as you mention, `pass` is based on simple flat files, there's no database that could break in the first place.